# Ionic 3 Login Authentication Using API - Cannot read property 'json' of null

Tags: angular, api, http, authentication, ionic3

I am doing authentication in Ionic 3 using API but In the login process, it is showing error: **Cannot read property 'json' of null**

This is my providers>restapi>restapi.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

let apiUrl = 'http://192.168.1.10/honeybee/HoneyApi/';

@Injectable()
export class RestapiProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestapiProvider Provider');
  }

  getUsers(credentials, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
      headers.append('Accept','application/json');
      headers.append('content-type','application/json');

      this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

This is my loginpage.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestapiProvider } from '../../providers/restapi/restapi';
import { ListPage } from '../list/list';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-loginpage',
  templateUrl: 'loginpage.html',
})
export class LoginpagePage {
  responseData : any;
  userData = {"email": "", "password": ""};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public restProvider: RestapiProvider) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginpagePage');
  }

  getloginUsers(){
    this.restProvider.getUsers(this.userData,'user_Login').then((result) => {
     this.responseData = result;
     if(this.responseData.userData){
     console.log(this.responseData);
     console.log("User Details");
     this.navCtrl.push(ListPage);
     }
     else{
       console.log("Incorrect Details"); }
    }, (err) => {
     // Error log
   });

 }

}
```

This is my loginpage.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>loginpage</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <form (submit)="getloginUsers()">
    <ion-list>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="userData.email" name="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="userData.password" name="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div padding>
        <button ion-button color="primary" block>Login</button>
      </div>

    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

I am getting a Cannot read property 'json' of null when I click the login button. Any help appreciated in Advance. Please Help.

Comment: Obviously your `res` object has a value of null, doesn't it? Do a `console.log(res)` to confirm it.

Comment: @Sébastien . Yes you are right but can you give the solution how to get values from the input fields. (loginpage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First***:

[ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) work if you addition `FormsModule` in config file.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule
    ...
  )],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [ ... ],
  providers: []
})
```

***Second***:

Send data as JSON format, add Content-Type:

```
getUsers(credentials, type) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return this.http
          .post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json());
}
```

and call in `loginpage`  (without Promise)

```
this.restProvider.getUsers(this.userData,'user_Login')
    .subscribe(res => this.responseData = result);
```

***Third***:

**Back-end must return success value**. If your API has error (no valid email, password) return [HTTP](https://httpstatuses.com/) error to Client.

---

*[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers must be implementation on the Server Part.*

Comment: In login.ts, I have declared userData = {"email": "", "password": ""}; thats why it is showing null .

Comment: stop stop. Have you null `credentials` or `res`?

Comment: `credentials` can't be null. And `res` is may. Because `res` is variable from api (let apiUrl = 'http://192.168.1.10/honeybee/HoneyApi/';)

Comment: It is taking null values, that's why it is showing json null error. Can you please provide the answer that will solve the null error.

Comment: I want it should take the values from the login.html.

Comment: Do you mean back-end implementation?

Comment: No, in the backend it is fine and in the loginpage.html and loginpage.ts. In loginpage.ts, I have defined this values thats why it is taking null, It should take from the loginpage.html. I have also checked the api in postman and it is working fine.

Comment: Okay, have you `this.userData = null` before send to getUsers? Can you set `console.log(this.userData); ` in `getloginUsers` **before**  `this.restProvider.getUsers(this.userData,'user_Login')`

Comment: possibly you lose context in `getloginUsers`. Can you add `console.log(this)` too in this method?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the method like this

### In your ts rest.api.ts File

```
getUsers(credentials, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
      headers.append('Accept','application/json');
      headers.append('content-type','application/json');

      this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res); ----- Change like this
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

### in your `loginpage.ts` file

```
   getloginUsers(){
    this.restProvider.getUsers(this.userData,'user_Login').then((result) => {
    if(result){
     this.responseData = result.json();
     if(this.responseData.userData){
     console.log(this.responseData);
     console.log("User Details");
     this.navCtrl.push(ListPage);
     }
     else{
       console.log("Incorrect Details"); }
    }
     }
     , (err) => {
     // Error log
   });

 }
```

Comment: In login.ts, I have declared userData = {"email": "", "password": ""}; thats why it is showing null .

Comment: How? I dont think so

Comment: In loginpage.ts, I have declared userData = {"email": "", "password": ""} and this.userData is taking null, Thats why it is giving null error.

Comment: So, when you enter the values through your application, it will automatically bind to userData.

Comment: In this result.json(); error is showing. Error: Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: Remove .json() then try

Answer (score 0):

Also, wouldn't it be easier to just return observable instead of a promise?

```
return this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your restapi.ts constructor, HttpClient causing the issue;

```
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestapiProvider Provider');
  }
```

Change that to this,

```
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    // console.log('Hello RestapiProvider Provider');
  }
```

You have an error on this part `{headers: headers}` here is your error :

> Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:
>   string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of
>   property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

Error is pretty clean so does not need any explanation, your code will work without any issue if you do that change. I tested on my local.