# My Footer selector is not working In Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am creating a page in Ionic and I have also created a separate component for the footer and I am using the footer selector in my page but It is showing the error.

This is my components>foot-card>foot-card.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'foot-card',
  templateUrl: 'foot-card.html'
})
export class FootCardComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello FootCardComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

This is my components.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FootCardComponent } from './foot-card/foot-card';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [FootCardComponent],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [FootCardComponent]
})

export class ComponentsModule {}
```

This is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { LoginpagePage } from '../pages/loginpage/loginpage';
import { FrontPage } from './../pages/front/front';
import { FooterPage } from './../pages/footer/footer';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RestapiProvider } from '../providers/restapi/restapi';
import { FootCardComponent } from '../components/foot-card/foot-card';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginpagePage,
    FrontPage,
    FooterPage,
    FootCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginpagePage,
    FrontPage,
    FooterPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    RestapiProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is the selector that i am using in my front page: (front.html)

```
<foot-card></foot-card>
```

but it is showing the error . I am new to ionic. Any help is much appreciated.

Error:

**Type FootCardComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ComponentsModule and AppModule! Please consider moving FootCardComponent to a higher module that imports ComponentsModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes FootCardComponent then import that NgModule in ComponentsModule and AppModule.**

Comment: Your template is in this case footer.html.. are you sure this isnt empty?

Comment: What is _the error_?

Comment: Yes. my footer.html is not empty. @Jonathan

Comment: @Silvermind . <page-footer> is not known element.

Comment: So actually it seems you want to use a Ionic Page as Component. You should create a component instead of a Page: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/

Comment: btw: here is a nice tutorial for creating a component: https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-custom-flash-card-component-in-ionic-2/

Comment: @Jonathan . But why do create a component. I have created a page and using the selector I can use it on other page like in Angular.

Comment: When you create a component, you can use it on all your Pages. But when you create something local in one Page like you do, you wont be able to use it in other pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185122/discussion-between-raghav-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Please follow the steps

Remove the `FootCardComponent` from the declaration part of **`app.module.ts`** file.

Add `ComponentsModule` in the import section of **`app.module.ts`** file.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { LoginpagePage } from '../pages/loginpage/loginpage';
import { FrontPage } from './../pages/front/front';
import { FooterPage } from './../pages/footer/footer';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RestapiProvider } from '../providers/restapi/restapi';
import { FootCardComponent } from '../components/foot-card/foot-card';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginpagePage,
    FrontPage,
    FooterPage,
    FootCardComponent **-------> *Remove this line***
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule, ---------> *Add ComponentsModule in import section*
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginpagePage,
    FrontPage,
    FooterPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    RestapiProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Let me know your outcome

Comment: You also have to add FootCardComponent in the entryComponents in app.module.ts. @Anand Raj.

Comment: Can you give the answer for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664700/ionic-3-login-authentication-using-api-cannot-read-property-json-of-null

Comment: Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Raghav Please I have added one answer. Please go through it

Answer (score 1):

Cut FootCardComponent from declarations and add it to Entry Components.
and let me know is this working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just, In the app.module.js: Remove FootCardComponent from declarations and add it to Entry Components. This solved my problem.

See [Ionic 4 custom components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185901/ionic-4-custom-components/53744129#53744129)